# Graph is not sending position of photos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo

We have a query to the Graph that was working very good until today.
https://graph.facebook.com/NNN/photos?fields=position,link,images

Now Facebook Graph is not sending the position (neither the link). Why?
Was there a change in the photos object or the fields or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running it through the api explorer? Works fine for me https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150146071791729%2Fphotos%3Ffields%3Dlink%2Cposition%2Cimages What error do you get? Is it related to an access_token? Is this using php of js?

Comment: Yeap... In the graph explorer works ok...

If I do the query in the Graph API Explorer the position Field appears ok: http://tqmadrid.com/ExplorerOK.gif

But If I query in my browser, the field position dont appears: http://tqmadrid.com/BrowserBad.gif
What happen?
Thanks

Comment: And I'm not getting any error.
Simply the graph api is not sending the position field I'm requesting.
And the app is in production months ago. The field position isn't returned since yesterday!

Comment: I found the problem!!!
Now this query needs the Access Token. It wasn't neccesarry days ago, but it seems that from yesterday its needed!

Comment: do you want to post it to help others?

Comment: Of course... 
Old query:
https://graph.facebook.com/NNN/photos?fields=id,link,position
New Query:
https://graph.facebook.com/10150931453167772/photos?access_token=BLABLA&fields=id,link,position

Answer (score 0):

OK... The problem is that now this query needs to include the Access Token.

Old query:
   https://graph.facebook.com/NNN/photos?fields=id,link,position

New Query:
   https://graph.facebook.com/NNN/photos?fields=id,link,position&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN